# Send multi-dimensional array request param to server

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jakarta-ee, datatables

Basically I will not do this if I have control in the front end, but when I am using `DataTable` [ajax](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) feature, they post the data like this:

```
columns[0][data]:0
columns[0][name]:
columns[0][searchable]:true
columns[0][orderable]:true
columns[0][search][value]:
columns[0][search][regex]:false
columns[1][data]:1
columns[1][name]:
columns[1][searchable]:true
columns[1][orderable]:true
columns[1][search][value]:
columns[1][search][regex]:false
columns[2][data]:2
columns[2][name]:
columns[2][searchable]:true
columns[2][orderable]:true
columns[2][search][value]:
columns[2][search][regex]:false
columns[3][data]:3
columns[3][name]:
columns[3][searchable]:true
columns[3][orderable]:true
columns[3][search][value]:
columns[3][search][regex]:false
columns[4][data]:4
columns[4][name]:
```

I have 2 questions:

1) how can I retrieve the value accordingly in servlet? `getParameterValues` can only get 1 dimensional array, I not sure how to retrieve the example above.

2) how can I retrieve the value if I am using Spring MVC?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use `getParameterNames()` or `getParameterMap()` and iterate over all of the parameters above. You see `request.getParameterValues()` will give you multiple values if *exactly the same* parameter is specified more than once: given `http://x.com/aaa?p=1&p=2&p=3`, `request.getParameterValues("p")` returns `["1","2","3"]` (always a string array).

Comment: @BalusC, I have asked how to do that in Spring MVC, does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967258/associative-array-request-parameter-parsing-with-java-servlet answer my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I roughly found the answer although it is not perfect:

1) I am confused about the array parameters, in fact, posting the data as above, it is not array parameters, I can purely extract the value via string, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6967258/associative-array-request-parameter-parsing-with-java-servlet).

2) For Spring MVC, I still can't find a way to convert request to an object, so for simplicity, I rather to receive the request param in `@RequestParam Map<String, String> params`, and iterate over each key. (Thanks @Nikos Paraskevopoulos for highlighting)